# Error when running test after compiling Solana program

Tags: solana-program, validator

Hey SolStackEx Community,

I was wondering if anyone could give me insight into the follow failure during a test of the Solana program.

```
[2023-12-09T16:44:49.378641832Z ERROR solana_core::validator] Rebuilding a new tower from the latest vote account due to failed tower restore: IO Error: NullTowerStorage::load() not available
[2023-12-09T16:44:49.378692024Z ERROR solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: tower_error error="Unable to restore tower: IO Error: NullTowerStorage::load() not available"
[2023-12-09T16:44:54.150216828Z ERROR solana_bench_tps::bench] funder has ◎0.000000000, needed ◎0.001539720
```

Does anyone have any insight into this?  Is this failure expected due to some missing component?  What is a tower in this context?  I see that a funder address has no Sol.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Please provide some more information about the command that you ran and from what directory. The first two logs are totally normal operation during tests, but the third one is specific to the bench-tps tests. Since it's just an error log and not an outright error, it might actually be ok! So please try to narrow down the command that you ran and the exact test that's failing

Comment: The exact order of operations was:

1: Download the repo at github.com/solana-labs/solana
2: Run cargo build inside the Solana directory
3: Run cargo test.  And then the error shows up.  

I am going to proceed and assume that it will either iron itself out as I move forward, or I'll deal with it if I have to.  Most of the test is passing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solana validator error, if you're using this validator just for testing your own programs, then you can simply reset the test validator.

Are you using the `solana-test-validator` command to start the validator? If so, try deleting the `test-ledger` dir in the path where the command was run. But you will have to redeploy your program if you do this.

If this doesn't solve your problem, add more details about your test setup, how are you starting the validator?

Comment: I just downloaded the gitrepo, ran cargo build which succeeded with adding a dependency or two, then run cargo test.  I am able to use everything normally from a normal Solana CLI install.  It just happens when downloading the repo.  I am running Ubuntu.  Also I am trying to set up a private Solana VM, but I am just at the start of working through that process.

Comment: I'll try deleting the ledger.  I did try to delete the target directory but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Just a followup, running the cargo test doesn't generate the test-ledger directory, so nothing to delete.  And for a bit more clarity, I am compiling the full suite from this repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana